# How can I change a child's state from the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, parent-child, state-management

So I have a React web page.

The parent component contains all of the children components (drop-downs, radio buttons, tables, etc.) Once I submit all of the forms with a button, I want all of the components states to return to null.

Is this possible without Redux. I know I should most definitely use Redux at this point and I am about to begin learning it in the next couple of days, but before jumping it i would just like to wrap my head around if what I am trying to do is possible/impossible without React.

Just for peace of mind and a full understanding.

Comment: Where do you store all component state right now? In each component?

Comment: I would ideally like to do so, so that a change of state for the drop-down does not cause an entire re-render of all child components within the parent. Correct me if I'm wrong, but is that not the case?

Comment: Right now, they are all in the parent. which seems to be inefficient to me.

Comment: Keeping them in the parent is the right way to do it! I posted a comment in the accepted answer below, let me find a link to the official docs that will better explain why

Comment: Some info [here about where state should live](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live) (your form needs to know what is in each input so it can send that info somewhere, so it makes sense for it to hold the state), [here about forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) (note that the form "owns" the state), and [here about lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) (which means moving part of the state up in the component tree by one or more level so that components that need to share the same state can access it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep all of the state values in the parent component and pass them down as props with a change handler to your presentational components. Then you can just reset the whole state when you submit the form. This is probably the most "react-y" way to do it.

If you don't want to do that, you could pass in a sort of "reset" prop to each of your child components and when this prop turns to true, reset the state, then reset the parent "reset" prop back to false. However, I personally don't think this is a great way to do this and would strongly recommend the first option.

Edit: You definitely don't need to introduce redux to accomplish what you're trying to do

Comment: The second option seems like the correct way to do it. The only reason I say this, and the reason I will most likely end up using React, is because if I keep all states in the parent component, anytime even a single drop-down switches states, the entire parent component re-renders, triggering every child component to re-render with it. I feel like the whole point of React is to have components render only when absolutely necessary and this seems to eliminate this most-important feature.

Comment: The first way is in fact the "correct" way to do it. Your reasoning is right in that the point of using React really is to have components render only when necessary, however your assumption that every child will be re-rendered when the parent component re-render is wrong (and that is good!). React does a diff so only components that did actually change will re-render, in this case only the components in the form that need to be reset!

Comment: Basically if you're using a "reset" flag yourself, then you're essentially reimplementing (one of the interesting parts of) React.

Comment: Thanks @bruno! I have been looking for this kind of answer/clarity for a week. Appreciate it a lot. Not that I doubt you because this makes the most sense, but I am going to see which ones re-render cause I remember some did.

Comment: @YoungScooter Yeah definitely! Exploring by yourself is the best way to make sure that things work the way you expect them to. Definitely toss some `console.log`s here and there to see when components re-render and to better understand the lifecycle of React components. [More info on state and lifecycle here too](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @BrunoEly So the reason I had my doubts is because before and now, when I change a drop-downs value, my date picker also re-renders. I can tell because I put a `console.log` in the render function. Am I doing something wrong here. I could show you the code if that helps.

Comment: @YoungScooter Maybe start a new question and post the code up there and send me the link!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178384/discussion-between-young-scooter-and-bruno-ely).

Answer (score 1):

As I upvoted, I recommend @Nick Swope's logic. Still, I want to provide two examples. I'm not sure this suits your situation but here are the examples.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    select: "",
  }

  defaultState = {
    name: "",
    select: "",
  };


  handleChane = e => this.setState( {
    [ e.target.name ]: e.target.value,
  } );

  handleSubmit = ( e ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( JSON.stringify( this.state ) );
    this.setState( this.defaultState );
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
        <Input onChange={this.handleChane} />
        <Select onChange={this.handleChane} />
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const Input = props => (
  <div>
    <input onChange={props.onChange} name="name" />
  </div>
);

const Select = props => (
  <div>
    <select onChange={props.onChange} name="select">
      <option>Choose one</option>
      <option>Foo</option>
      <option>Bar</option>
      <option>Baz</option>
    </select>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In this example, you keep a default state and after form submission, you reset the state. As you can see, form values still there. Now, here is the second option:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    select: "",
  }

  defaultState = {
    name: "",
    select: "",
  };

  formRef = React.createRef();

  handleChane = e => this.setState( {
    [ e.target.name ]: e.target.value,
  } );

  handleSubmit = ( e ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( JSON.stringify( this.state ) );
    this.setState( this.defaultState );
    this.formRef.current.reset();
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return (
      <form ref={this.formRef} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
        <Input onChange={this.handleChane} />
        <Select onChange={this.handleChane} />
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const Input = props => (
  <div>
    <input onChange={props.onChange} name="name" />
  </div>
);

const Select = props => (
  <div>
    <select onChange={props.onChange} name="select">
      <option>Choose one</option>
      <option>Foo</option>
      <option>Bar</option>
      <option>Baz</option>
    </select>
  </div>
);
```

Here, you rest your state and clear your form using a ref. I can't put this into the snippet since React version is a little bit older here.

Answer (score 0):

Parent component can have a `reset` state that is triggered by the form submit button, and pass it as a prop to its children, in your case all the form elements(drop-downs, radio buttons, tables, etc.).

Then the children could react on this `reset` prop in its life-cycle hook (componentWillReceiveProps or getDerivedStateFromProps).

Answer (score -1):

A few simple options:

1) reload the whole page:

```
  location.reload();
```

2) remount the App component:

```
 reactDOM.unmount(document.body);
 reactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Comment: This would cause the whole page to reset, though, not just the form